# Nested $http call within angular.forEach and loader show

Tags: angularjs, ajax

I'm trying to show loader until all POST CALL till 4th level has not completed.
code is like

```
angular.forEach(level1, function(value,key){
  $http({
     type : POST,
     data : value
  }).then(function(success){
       angular.forEach(level2,function(value2,key2){
         $http({
            type : POST,
            data : { success, value2}
         }).then(function(success){
             .. Till level 4
         },function(error){});
       });
  },function(error){});
});
```

How can wait till complete execution should complete level4. Every level has its own angular,forEach()

Answer (score 1):

Use $q.all() to wait until all promises of a particular level complete

```
var promises = [];
var level =1;
angular.forEach(level1, function(value,key){
 var promise = $http({
     type : POST,
     data : value})
 promises.push(promise);
})
//inject the $q libary
$q.all(promises).then(function(){
  level = 2;
  promises = [];
  angular.forEach(level2, function(value,key){
 var promise = $http({
     type : POST,
     data : value})
 promises.push(promise);
})
})
```

//rinse and repeat until level 4

Comment: But Here, I have dependency of last success call to current POST data and current success data's reference in next success call. .. I can't use different functions and $q.all(promises) as u stated.